# Monotone Convergence Theorem for sets of functions instead of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have a *set* $S$ (as opposed to a *sequence*) of non-negative real-valued functions with

$$\hat{s}(x) := \sup \{s(x) ~|~ s \in S\}~.$$

Does

$$\sup \left\{\int s(x) ~ d \mu  ~\middle|~ s \in S \right\} ~{}={}~ \int \hat{s} ~d \mu$$

hold for the Lebesgue integral, where $\mu$ is a probability measure with countable support?

Comment: To speak of monotonicity, you need an ordering on $S$. If your set is such that for all $s,t \in S$ we have $s \geqslant t$ or $t \geqslant s$ - where $f \geqslant g$ means $f(x) \geqslant g(x)$ for all x - and $s \geqslant 0$ for some $s \in S$, then it looks credible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not hold.

For $c \in [0,1]$ consider $\chi_{\{c\}}$, the indicator function of the set $\{c\}$.

$\chi_{\{c\}}$ is measurable since $\{c\}$ is measurable, and we have:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{\{c\}} \,d\lambda= \lambda(\{c\}) = 0$$

The pointwise supremum of the set of functions $\left\{\chi_{\{c\}} : c \in [0,1]\right\}$ is the function $\chi_{[0,1]}$.

We have:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{[0,1]} \,d\lambda= \lambda([0,1]) = 1$$

Comment: What if $\lambda$ has only countable support, i.e. single points have a positive probability? Does it still not hold?

Comment: @blk It still doesn't hold. Let $\delta = \delta_0 + \delta_1$, the sum of Dirac measures at $0$ and $1$. Consider $\chi_{\{0\}}$ and $\chi_{\{1\}}$. Their pointwise supremum is $\chi_{\{0, 1\}}$. We have:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_{\{0\}} \,d\delta = \int_\mathbb{R} \chi_{\{1\}} \,d\delta = 1$$
but
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_{\{0, 1\}} \,d\delta = \delta\{0,1\} = 2$$

Comment: But now in $\delta$ you gave a probability of 1 to two distinct points, so $\delta$ is not a probability measure.

Comment: @blk You didn't specify that it needed to be a probability measure. In that case simply take $\frac12 \delta$ and the same two functions.